# What is the church secret?

Tags: puzzle-creation

This is really a request to make a puzzle.  I am sometimes made to go to church. On the wall will be a series of what I would to think are secret clues and I would love to make a puzzle from them. The ones from this week were:

```
12
Ps 85
500
282
3
Blank
```

The Blank was just a space where I feel I was being asked to provide an answer.

Is there a good puzzle that can be made from these?

Comment: Will you give the name of the hymn book? We known where to find Psalm 85. The blank is presumably just an empty space, for when there is another psalm or hymn.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't know the name :(  If there is a standard one we could use that. Yes that is what  the blank is for in reality but I like to think it's really a puzzle they are setting us and that is where I have to write the answer.

Comment: Which denomination is your church?  That might help identify the hymn book.

Comment: @dan04 It's a "liberal, Anglo-Catholic church"

Comment: If you are in the church, you should know what hymn book they use, because they will be provided for the congregation to sing from. I am tickled by the fact that you are "made to go to church". What's liberal about that?

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't look at the literature. I mostly just look at the walls and wonder about puzzles.

Comment: I respect your imagination, but it seems not all of the congregation are singing from the same hymn sheet.

Comment: @WeatherVane I was hoping someone could invent a picture using the number sequence.

Comment: @Simd, the idea is that *you* create the puzzle from your inspiration :)